# How to list all available named colors

Tags: color

Is there a comand or way to get list of all available predefined (named) colors on my actual system?

Not a question regarding xcolor or any other color enhancement. Just minimalistic setup.

Comment: `grep "definecolor{" $(kpsewhich color.sty)`

Comment: For the colors defined by `xcolor` take a look in the `.def` files in the directory `$TEXMF/tex/latex/xcolor/`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Is it that color package is loaded automatically even without using \usepackage?

Comment: @PetrMatousu No. To use colors you need to load the `color` package, or a package, which depends on it. In plain LaTeX `\color=undefined`.

Comment: pages 38ff in http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf